# How to make nested ifs

Tags: bash, scripting, test

I'm trying to make my own command using a script but I'm having a bit of doubt about the proper way to create an if inside another one. The code below shows how I'm trying to do it, but I guess it's not right.

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -z $1
then
    echo "Wrong usage of command, to check proper wars user -h for help."
    exit
else
    if test "$1"="-h"
    then
        echo "OPTIONS:  -h (help), -a (access point MAC), -c (current target[s] MAC[s])
"
        exit
    fi

    if test "$1"="-c"
    then
        echo "Usage error, access point MAC comes first."
        exit
    fi
fi
```

Comment: 1) [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). 2) What makes you think it's not right, or that there's something unusual? What happens with your script?

Comment: In addition to @MichaelHomer's comments, whenever you have a shell script syntax error or other problem, your first step should be to cut and paste your code into
[shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  Open a question here only if shellcheck fails to spot the problem or gives you a message that you don't understand.

Comment: My 2 cents: test for failure/exit conditions, and if they match, report it then exit. Then start the next test(s) in a new “if” block so that you don’t end up indented 20 columns when you’re writing the most important code.

Answer (score 1):

Your nested `if` statements look mostly fine, your tests are likely what is causing your script to "not work."

I've changed your `test`s to the bash `[[` extended test command.

Also instead of using two nested `if` conditionals I think it should work fine as a single `if` `elif`.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$1" ]]
then
    echo "Wrong usage of command, to check proper wars user -h for help."
    exit
else
    if [[ "$1" == "-h" ]]
    then
        echo -e "OPTIONS:  -h (help), -a (access point MAC), -c (current target[s] MAC[s])\n"
        exit
    elif [[ "$1" == "-c" ]]
    then
        echo "Usage error, access point MAC comes first."
        exit
    fi
fi
```

---

Your tests should have a space between `$1` and your test string but I think it is better to use the bash `[[` test instead if you are going to be writing your script in bash.  Here are some examples of how the `test` builtin works:

```
$ test true && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ test false && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ test true=false && echo yes || echo no
yes
$ test true = false && echo yes || echo no
no
```

---

Additionally in this instance I don't think your nested `if` conditional is required at all.  You could simplify it to:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" == "-h" ]]; then
    echo -e "OPTIONS:  -h (help), -a (access point MAC), -c (current target[s] MAC[s])\n"
    exit
elif [[ "$1" == "-c" ]]; then
    echo "Usage error, access point MAC comes first."
    exit
else
    echo "Wrong usage of command, to check proper wars user -h for help."
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Also, `case ... esac` for less typing and arguably neater code.